# select a parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have some HTML that looks like this,

```
<div id="music_interests">
    <ul class="interests">
        <li >
        <div class="interest inline">
        <img src=""/>
        <div class="interest_popup">
            1 users have this interest.
        <a href="http://localhost/love/index.php/my_profile/remove_interest/34" class="button red upper rounded_5 small remove">Remove interest</a>                                     </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

When users clicks the remove button I need to select the parent div (in this case music_interests). How would I go about that?

I have tried doing the following,

`$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()` but is there a more elegant way?

To complicate things futher I will not actually no the parents ID when in the app as the remove button occurs in 4 or 5 different areas on the page.

Comment: @everybody : Nobody votes on questions. Questions should be voted too. Some might need points to place Bounties.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, A mere 7 minutes of asking effort doesn't worth upvote. people should first google for options available in jQuery and then come to stackoverflow with their specific problem. This way we are just increasing number of duplicate questions on SO. And when it comes to compensate for bunties, OP has enough reputation to start a bounty. If you see my profile I have almost equal numbers of vote casts on questions and answers.

Comment: I wonder OP avoided so many similar questions to follow while typing the title of own question. And still people considering the question has some research effort.

Comment: @tusar I was not meaning (strictly) on this.question; Just general thinking. While some answers get upvoted up to 10< votes, OP (who really need votes) end up forgotten. It's a general (minor) problem on SO that was already discussed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('div#music_interests');
//find the nearest div with id "music_interests"
//if i omitted the id, it retrieves the div with class "interest_popup"
```

or [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$(this).parents('div:eq(1)');
//get ALL the ancestor divs (until it reaches root tag)
//since music_interests is just 2 levels up, use :eq(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ID of the DIV you want to remove is static you should only use the ID selector (not something like **$("div#music_interests")**) as the ID selector is directly mapped to the DOM function *document.getElementsById* which is pretty fast:

```
$("#music_interests").remove();
```

If the ID isn't static you could get the UL just like that:

```
$(function(){ //execute when page has been loaded
    $(".remove").click(function(){ //attach click handler
        var removeDiv = $(this).closest("ul").parent().remove(); //get next UL -> DIV is its parent
        return false; //stop further processing of "click" event
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if remove button always exist in ul tag (in all your 4 or 5 different areas) then you can use the following code.

```
$(this).closest("ul").parent()
```

in this case u don't even need to give id to DIV tags